# How to add sequencial number in equal strings in EXCEL for usernames

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

The idea is that: 
I separate full names into 2 other columns like fname + lname.

Then, I concatenate fname.lname to create a username.

So, we have got: 
fname.lname@server.com

However, sometimes we find out there are few equal usernames and we need to handle it to become different from each other.

Then, we wanted to make an incrementation every username repeatition:

1. fname.lname1@server.com
2. fname.lname2@server.com
3. fname.lname3@server.com

**How to meet this condition when working with EXCEL?**

I'm really beging your help guys! 
How to AUTO make SequecialUserName happens in Excel

Comment: Use COUNTIFS...

Comment: I have no idea how it works.. I tried twice. But I didn't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=A2&"."&B2&IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)>1,COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2),"")&"@server.com"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You really helped me! I say: a lot